# Favorite Tags on meta site looks terrible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I added election to my list of favorite tags on meta, to see what questions would be asked for a potential moderator. Well, this is what my screen looked like this morning:

[image]

I hope you can see that the light grey text on white background is pretty unreadable...

Comment: Nice highly readable white background, like on any normal site. I don't see what you're complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a fix that didn't work, or a different browser rendering differently, but I saw this from a different machine running Firefox just now. It's better, but the number of votes can't be read...[image]

Comment: I see this color scheme too, on Chrome 16 on Linux.

Comment: It was a start :) That issue and some others should be fixed now.

Comment: @balpha: It is now better, but at least in some cases, the number of views is not being displayed either. I'm trying to figure out the exact configuration, but I'm running Firefox 9.0.1